# Json data parsing using php

Tags: php, json, curl

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/IN/INR/en-US/del/ccu/2017-04-20/?apikey=prtl6749387986743898559646983194");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

print_r(json_decode($result));
```

HOW TO PARSE CARRIER NAME AND QUOTES PRICE OF ABOVE CODE

Comment: your *json* rather looks like **XML** to me. so continue on that information.

Comment: http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/IN/INR/en-US/del/ccu/2017-04-20/?apikey=prtl6749387986743898559646983194

Comment: parse these api in php

Comment: That. Is. XML. JSON != XML. Completely different. PHP has XML parsing functions. Use those.

Comment: Please send code

Comment: @ravitopa Um... no. Go do your own work :/

Comment: please do it i don't know how to parse it please sir

Comment: No time like the present to learn.

Comment: i will pay you please do it sir

Answer (score -4):

You are almost there. Try something like this:

You can use `json_decode($result, true)` and it will be treated as an associative array rather than `stdClass`.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/IN/INR/en-US/del/ccu/2017-04-20/?apikey=prtl6749387986743898559646983194");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl); // is json
curl_close($curl);

$json = @json_decode($result);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($json);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
foreach ($json->Quotes as $quote) {
    print_r($quote);
}
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
foreach ($json->Places as $place) {
    print_r($place);
}
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
foreach ($json->Carriers as $carrier) {
    print_r($quote);
}
echo "</pre>";

?>
```